# Android handlers don't work on specified interval of time

Tags: android, android-handler, android-vibration

I am building an Android app and I need to have short vibrations at specific intervals in case some conditions are met.

The problem is that, when those conditions are met, even tho I set the device to vibrate for 2 seconds, it sometimes vibrates over 10 seconds and sometimes the vibrations don't stop until the device is restarted.
Also, I noticed that the runnable inside the handler doesn't run at the correct interval of time. It should be every *interval* seconds, but it usually takes more than that.

Here's an example:

```
fullBatteryHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                if(isBatteryFull){
                    Log.d("vibrate", "full battery");
                    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(2000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                }
                fullBatteryHandler.postDelayed(this, interval * 1000);
            }
         }, 1000);
```

Any ideas why that happens?

EDIT: I fixed the issue by adding a WakeLock.

Comment: Maybe the handler is being invoked more than once? Do you see `full battery` multiple times in logcat?

Comment: Well, I see it once every *interval* seconds when it checks if the battery is full. But I think that's how it should work. At first I had that problem, the handler was invoked several times and I tought that was the problem. But it is only invoked once now and the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int interval = 1;
fullBatteryHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                if(isBatteryFull){
                    Log.d("vibrate", "full battery");
                    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(2000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                    fullBatteryHandler.postDelayed(this, (interval + 2) * 1000);
                } else {
                    fullBatteryHandler.postDelayed(this, interval * 1000);
                }
            }
         }, 1000);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It only vibrates once and then doesn't go in the run() again.

Comment: How much times it should vibrate?

Comment: It should vibrate for 2 seconds every *interval* seconds while battery level is 100 and device is charging. I'm sure I've done the conditions right and it enters that if() only if battery is full and device is on charger.

Comment: I have updated. If battery is full you need vibrate 2 seconds and wait until it ends and start new postDelay.

Comment: ```2020-10-19 17:21:03.695 32422-32422/com.example.com D/vibrate: full battery
2020-10-19 17:23:05.564 32422-32422/com.example.com D/vibrate: full battery
2020-10-19 17:25:52.822 32422-32422/com.example.com D/vibrate: full battery  ``` It worked well for a while, but at some point it started doing it at wrong interval again

Comment: I replaced my code in the run() method with yours. And I didn't use your interval, mine is 30 seconds currently.

Comment: Ah, and also the problem with the vibrations remain, they are sometimes longer than they should. I think this is a thread problem rather than a problem with my code. I'm guessing this Handler runs on the UI thread and somehow it gets delayed by some other operations that are ran on that thread. I'm not sure, I don't really know how Handlers and Threads work on Android, I'm a beginner. So I have a class that extends BroadcastReceiver and  implements SensorEventListener. In the onReceive() method of this class I create this handler once.

Comment: In my opinion, onReceive() method calls one more time and handler executes in different time.

Comment: I created a global boolean that is initialized as false, and once it initializes the handler it is set to true. The handler is only initialized when the boolean is false. Is there any chance the boolean resets at some point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223301/discussion-between-yeldar-n-and-liviu-pinzaru).